# Are algorithms off topic on SO?

Tags: discussion

I'm asking this question as a result of the close vote [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086845/is-there-a-term-for-a-tree-where-the-values-of-the-children-add-up-to-a-fixed-va?noredirect=1#comment37148871_24086845).

According to a very high rep user, algorithmic questions should be moved to the mathematics Stack Exchange. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, although this might be more fit for [Computer Science](http://cs.stackexchange.com/). SO is for the implementation of algorithms; math and cs are more appropriate for discussing those algorithms.

Answer (score 3):

Questions about software algorithms and data structures are absolutely on-topic on Stack Overflow. The [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is clear on this. Just because another site is open to these types of questions does not automatically make them off-topic on SO. There are areas of overlap between many sites in the network.

Having said that, the question you linked to doesn't look like it's really about a software algorithm. It's asking if a particular kind of tree has a name. That kind of vocabulary question generally doesn't last long on Stack Overflow. It's not likely to be very useful to other people in the future, so it probably should be closed. I don't know if one of the other sites mentioned in the comments to that question would be open to having it migrated or not. I'll ask the moderators on those sites.

---

Update: The CS moderators have accepted that question, so it's now migrated.

Comment: I was under the impression that the **implementation** of algorithms was on topic but the **discussion, explanation, selection** etc of algorithms was off topic.

Comment: @indivisible Questions asking for an explanation of an algorithm should be fine. It's really up to the OP if they want to ask those on SO or CS. Questions asking for the selection of an algorithm would probably be closed as being a recommendation question, too broad, or primarily opinion based, not really because they're algorithm questions.

Comment: I have another question which was closed in SO. Does it also match the criteria of CS? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25105599/algorithm-for-finding-similar-images-using-an-index - personally I think it's more a question for SO, but they don't want it

Comment: @DanielAlder Questions asking for tools and libraries are off-topic network wide, with the exception of the [Software Recommendation](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site. Be sure to read their posting guidelines before asking there, though. http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic